# AngularJS: Injecting a factory / service with identical name but under different module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Let's say I have three factories of the same name `DSerrorLog` each under different module

```
angular.module('module1').factory('DSerrorLog', function () {
    return { show: false, msg: "" };
});
angular.module('module2').factory('DSerrorLog', function () {
    return { show: false, msg: "" };
});
angular.module('module3').factory('DSerrorLog', function () {
    return { show: false, msg: "" };
});
```

How do I inject the correct instances from the correct module one e.g. `DSerrorLog` under `module3` into my controller? I suppose syntax such as `module3.DSerrorLog` won't work here.

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['module1', 'module2', 'module3'])
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, DSerrorLog) {
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cool question!

It turns out that the order that you include them affects which one you get. Basically each module in add will overwrite the injector. So in your example DSerrorLog will be from module3 if you just inject it normally.

Turns out you can still get the injector for other modules if you want to use them. Here is a fiddle where I show how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/7YH7p/

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$injector', 'test', 
    function($scope, $injector, test) {
        $scope.injected = test.data;
        var inj = angular.injector(['mod1']);
        $scope.my_inject = inj.get('test').data;
}]);
```

The two have different values!

Hope this helped!