# Dependency on service/factory with same name from different module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, angular-services

I am trying to create a service in a module which is dependent on another service in another module but the services have the same name. Consider the following example:

```
angular.module('module1',[]).factory('log', [function () {
    return { show: false, msg: "" };
}]);

angular.module('module2', ['module1']).factory('log', ['log', function (log) {
    return { show: false, msg: log.msg + "" };
}]);

angular.module('myapp', ['module2']);
```

When I implement the above code get:
    Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: log

I understand that services are singleton in angular [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762228/confused-about-service-vs-factory)] and the dependency injection follows last one wins convention [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594441/angularjs-injecting-a-factory-service-with-identical-name-but-under-different)]. Seems to me that in 'module2', 'log' that gets injected is itself hence the circular dependency. How do I inject 'log' from 'module1'?

Comment: Is it necessary that you have to keep the name log for both of your services?

Comment: Yes, both of the service needs to have the same name. I want to extend the functionality of 'module1' and not make changes to 'myapp' other than update the dependencies.
I know that having different service names would prevent this issue, it is how my app is at the moment.

Comment: I think this is a shortcoming of angular if there is no way to refer to a service with fully qualified name (something like module name + service name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I solved it then using [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator).